# Node.js v0.10: Replace certain bytes in file without reading whole file

Tags: node.js, file-io

I am making a text editor and for editing a file I really need some sort of way to only read certain bytes from a file, which I've achieved using `fs.createReadStream` uisng the `start` and `end` options.

I also need to replace certain bytes in the file. I am not sure how this can be done. So far the best solution I've come up is to read the file using a stream and then write to a new file, when I come across the bytes I'm looking for I write my new content instead, thus replacing the old stuff with the new stuff.

This is not the best way, as you'll probably know. To edit 4 bytes I am reading a huge 2GB file and writing the 2GB (assuming I'm editing a 2GB file), not efficient in the least.

What is the best way to achieve this? I've spent two weeks doing this and I've also thought of using Buffers, but Buffers load the entire file into memory, which again is unefficient if it's a 2GB file.

How would you achieve replacing certain bytes in a file without reading the entire file and without installing some npm package that has C++ code. I don't want my editor to have to compile C++ code.

If doing that is not straightforward, how about deleting certain bytes from a file without reading the entire file? If I can do that then I can delete the bytes to be replaced and use something like `fs.write()` to add the ones I want them to be replaced with.

**Edit #1:**

After playing around, I've found that if I open a file with `fs.open` with flag `r+` and then `fs.write` that *replaces* stuff. So if the text is "Lorem ipsum" and I `fs.write` "!!!!" the result will be "!!!!m ipsum".

This would work fine if only all the stuff I was going to write was the perfect length. :/

I know what to do in the case that the new content isn't the perfect length, but I don't know how. :/ Maybe if there was some sort of "empty byte"...

**Edit #2:**

So as said above, `fs.open` (with `r+` flags option) + `fs.write` allow me to overwrite the content in a file without reading the entire file, which is terrific. Now with this I am running into a new problem. Let's take the following file:

```
one\n
two\n
three\n
```

If I `fs.open` at byte 0 and then `fs.write` "yes", I end up with:

```
yes\n
two\n
three\n
```

If I do the same but instead `fs.write` "niet", I end up with:

```
niettwo\n
three\n
```

Notice how the `\n` character was replaced with the "t", this is because of how `fs.write` works by replacing bytes when using `r+` in `fs.open`. This is the problem I am trying to solve right now.

How would one go about doing something like "from this byte to this byte, replace it with these other bytes" so my function could be something like `function replaceBytes(filePath, newBytes, startByte, endByte)` and that would replace only from `startByte` to `endByte`, no matter how long `newBytes`, whether it be shorter or longer than the length of `endByte - startByte`.

**Edit #3:**

OK, I figured out the case where the new content is longer than the old content that is being replaced. Thanks to `\x00`, I've been able to figure it out. In case both the new and the old content are the same length, that's not hard to figure out as there's nothing to do there.

But the case where the old content is shorter than the new content, that's still unresolved.

For those curious, this is the working code for old content longer than new content: https://github.com/noedit/file/blob/592a35134440a03d3e3c3e366f6cda7f565c11aa/lib/replaceBytes.js#L27-L34

Although it does put a null byte in there, which depending on the editor, it may show up as a character and thus looking weird. :/

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for something that's impossible, because file systems can't expand and contract in the middle of a file.  Do you have any indication that this has been done by any other program?

Comment: @AaronDufour I *assume* text editors written in C have done this before, as otherwise it's incredibly unefficient to edit big files... Unless all the text editors do a temporary file thing, where they write the entire file into a temporary file, with the modifications made, and then rm the old file and mv the new file into position. Or something like that. That sounds incredibly unefficient...

Comment: The C stdlib doesn't offer anything that would allow you to do what you're asking (again, because file systems don't allow it).  However, writing to a file can be done in the background, so it shouldn't have any noticeable effect.

Comment: @AaronDufour Huh... Good to know. Now I know the past month I was chasing an empty dream, so to speak. lol. Well thank you for that, I'll be working on streams then I guess. Should I leave this question open or should I close it?

Comment: Even an answer of "that's not possible" can be valuable to future readers.  I would suggest not closing this, although that is of course up to you.  I've left an answer that summarizes/expands on my comments here, in case that is helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you've discovered, `fs.write` with `r+` mode allows you to overwrite bytes.  This suffices for the case where the added and deleted pieces are exactly the same length.

When the added text is shorter than the deleted text, I advise that you not fill in with `\x00` bytes, as you suggest in one of your edits.  Those are perfectly valid characters in most types of files (in source code, they will usually cause the compiler/interpreter to throw an error).

The short answer is that this is not generally possible.  This is not an abstraction issue; at the file system level, files are stored in chunks of contiguous bytes.  There is no generic way to insert/remove from the middle of a file.

The correct way to do this is to seek to the first byte you need to change, and then write the rest of the file (unless you get to a point at which you've added/deleted the same number of bytes, in which case you can stop writing).

In order to avoid issues with crashing during a long write or something like that, it is common to write to a temporary file location and then `mv` the temporary file in place of the actual file you wish to save.

Comment: in my opinion this is the correct answer, and the most important part is the last sentence

Answer (score 4):

Try below code snippet:

**New Solution:**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var startByte = 3,
      endByte = 6,
    newBytes ='replacing with this line',
    filePath ='sample.txt';

function replaceBytes(filePath, startByte, endByte, newBytes)
{

  var fsWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream('temp.txt', {flags: 'w+'});
  var fsReadStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath, {start: endByte+1});
  fsReadStream.pipe(fsWriteStream);

  fsWriteStream.on('finish', function(){
    var fsReadStream2 = fs.createReadStream('temp.txt');
    var fsWriteStream2 = fs.createWriteStream(filePath, {start: startByte, flags: 'r+'});
    fsWriteStream2.write(newBytes);
    fsReadStream2.pipe(fsWriteStream2);
    //fsWriteStream2.end(); 
  });


}

replaceBytes(filePath, startByte, endByte, newBytes);
```

**Old Solution:**

s - start byte

R - text to be replaced with

file - file where text has to be replaced

```
var fs = require('fs');
var s = 3,
    R ='replacing with this line',
    file ='sample.txt';

function replace(file, s, R)
{
  var N = R.length;
  var fsWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream(file, {start: s, flags: 'r+'});
  fsWriteStream.write(R);
  fsWriteStream.end(); 
}

replace(file, s, R);
```

Comment: Tried it out, this seems to be the same as what I posted about using `fs.open` and `fs.write`. Am I wrong? Also because the flag is `a+`, a version of `a`, of which Linux does not support positional writes, the `start` option is not useable if you're using the `a` flag and expect your code to be used in Linux (which I do). :/

Comment: I tested it on Mac(OSX) and its working. Can you try with r+ option on Linux?

Comment: I do not currently have access to a Linux machine, but I am taking the documentation's word on this and assuming that `r+` works as intended but `a` or `a+` doesn't. Still, this does not solve the problem I am currently running into. Will shortly update the question. :)

Comment: This cannot be achieved without using temporary file. I wrote raw code, can you try and see ?

Comment: Yeah I tried it out, as I said on my first comment. :) It has the same observable behaviour as `fs.open` + `fs.write`, with the exception that this is a stream of course.

Comment: OK, I just noticed your question has a huge edit, I didn't notice that, sorry. From what I can tell is going on, you're reading the original file, writing it up to a certain point, to a new file (temporary file), then inserting our new content, then continuing the write skipping the old content. Is this correct? If it is, this is the solution that I currently have going on, which is not ideal because HUGE files like 2GB files would take a really long time to read and write. :/

Answer (score 3):

If you open a file manually (`fs.open()` with an appropriate file mode like `r+`), you can then use `fs.write()` to write at a specific position within the file.

If you need more flexible file seeking, there are modules on npm such as [`fs-ext`](https://github.com/baudehlo/node-fs-ext) that provide [`fs.seek()`](https://github.com/baudehlo/node-fs-ext#fsseekfd-offset-whence-callback) that allows you to seek to some offset *n* bytes from the current position for example.

Comment: Sadly `fs-ext` has C++ compilation going on. I looked into `fs.open()` and `fs.write()` but it doesn't seem like they provide the deleting certain bytes from a file stuff I'm looking for. :(

Comment: Well there is no single function for deleting (actual removal and not just marking as `0x00`) individual bytes. For that you'd need to do it manually by overwriting *n* byte(s) to be deleted with the bytes *after* the byte(s) to be be deleted (and truncating *n* bytes from the end of the file).

Comment: So basically I'd mark the bytes I want to delete as `0x00`, truncate *n* amount of bytes from file (according to how many I added), then add the new content I want to replace it with using `fs.open` and `fs.write`?